# Is my understanding about this complex contour integral correct?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image: Contour]

I have to evaluate $$\int_{\gamma} \sin(z)\cos(2z)dz$$ over the above contour.

My question is:

Is the info given sufficient to solve this problem (just the contour image and integral) and can I take $1$ and $-0.5$ as my endpoints/bounds to solve this integral?

Comment: Where does $\gamma$ start and where does it end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the integrand is holomorphic (in the whole $\mathbb{C}$), then the result for any path integral just will depend on the end points. Now, you have that

$$
\sin (z)\cos (2z)=\frac1{4i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})(e^{i2z}+e^{-i2z})=\frac1{4i}(e^{i3z}-e^{-i3z})=\frac1{2}\sin (3z)
$$

Then if you have a path $\gamma $ who end points are $A$ and $B$ and you travel it from $A$ to $B$ then as $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(-\frac1{6}\cos (3z))=\frac1{2}\sin (3z)$ you have that

$$
\int_{\gamma }\sin (z)\cos (2z)\,d z=\frac1{2}\int_{\gamma }\sin (3z)\,d z=-\frac1{6}\cos (3z)\bigg|_{z=A}^{z=B}
$$

For your case you have that $A=-i\frac1{2}$ and $B=i$.

Comment: But does it matter in which direction it starts or ends?

Comment: @AhsonYousef yes, it matters. Depending on the direction you travel the path the sign of the integral will change